# How do I use virtual joysticks in Unity2d ()top view?

Tags: unity, c#, 2d

I want to use virtual joysticks for character movement, in a top-down 2D game, that includes rotating the character.

I tried an Easy Joystick Unity Package, but it doesn't work properly, so what do I do?
Does anyone have a script (preferably in C#) that would use virtual joysticks to move a character?

Comment: I want to do a joystick c# code, not package. For rotate and movement

Comment: If you find you're not getting answers, a good strategy can be to edit your question to add more details - like what code you're currently using to move your character, or what specific symptoms you got from the previous attempt that "didn't work properly." Even if these things might seem obvious to you, writing them out can provide other users with leads about how to help you.